# construct a list with multiple dictionaries with table header and each row in pyqt5;

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have taken the column header name in a list called 'headers' and each row data in list called 'row data', when I convert two `list` into `dict` I am not getting all those values instead I am only getting unique key values, how to get all duplicate values.

```
headers=['Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1']
rowdata=['US_CO', 'US_COM', 'US_DO', 'public', 'US_CO', 'US_COM', 'US_DO', 'publicss', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

```py
def savedata_click(self):
    headers = []
    rowdata = []
    for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
        for column in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            item = self.table.item(row, column)
            if item is not None:
                rowdata.append(item.text())
            else:
                rowdata.append('')
            header = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(column)
            if header is not None:
                headers.append(header.text())
            else:
                headers.append("Column " + str(column))
     res= dict(zip(headers,rowdata))
     print(res)

output:{'Filter1':  '', 'Filter2':  '', 'Filter3':  '', 'SchemaName1':  ''}
expected:[{'Filter1':  'US_CO', 'Filter2':  'US_COM', 'Filter3':  'US_DO', 'SchemaName1':  'public'},{'Filter1':  'US_CO', 'Filter2':  'US_COM', 'Filter3':  'US_DO', 'SchemaName1':  'publicss'},{'Filter1':  '', 'Filter2':  '', 'Filter3':  '', 'SchemaName1':  ''},{'Filter1':  '', 'Filter2':  '', 'Filter3':  '', 'SchemaName1':  ''}]
```

Comment: @shaikmoeed.. The Header is table column name brother . how to get the same header as key for each row.

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
headers=['Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1', 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3', 'SchemaName1']
rowdata=['US_CO', 'US_COM', 'US_DO', 'public', 'US_CO', 'US_COM', 'US_DO', 'publicss', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

---

```
>>> final_list = []      
>>> header_length = 4 # Number of columns
>>> _splitted_dict_list = [{k:v} for k,v in zip(headers, rowdata)]           
>>> for v in range(0, len(_splitted_dict_list), header_length):
    final_list.append({nk:nv for nested_dict in _splitted_dict_list[v:v+4] for nk,nv in nested_dict.items()})
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> final_list

[{'Filter1': 'US_CO','Filter2': 'US_COM','Filter3': 'US_DO','SchemaName1': 'public'},
 {'Filter1': 'US_CO','Filter2': 'US_COM','Filter3': 'US_DO','SchemaName1': 'publicss'},
 {'Filter1': '', 'Filter2': '', 'Filter3': '', 'SchemaName1': ''},
 {'Filter1': '', 'Filter2': '', 'Filter3': '', 'SchemaName1': ''},
 {'Filter1': '', 'Filter2': '', 'Filter3': '', 'SchemaName1': ''}]
```